# Need help in Instantiating a prefab at a desired position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a bullet in a 2D game. But the bullet spawns exactly at the center of my player(a 2D ufo). I have tried adding an vector3 to it but the bullet doesn't seem to use it. It spawns incorrectly but rotates correctly.

```
     Instantiate(bulletPrefab, Player.transform.position, 
      Player.transform.rotation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because of the line `Player.transform.position` what you're actually coding is, `"Spawn my prefab, at the location of my player, with that rotation of my player"`

Instantiate is really three parts
`What do I want to spawn?` `Where do I want to put it?` `What rotation should it have?`

So, you want to rework your code to take in a desired location and rotation.

```
Instantiate(bulletPrefab, desiredSpawnPos, desiredRotation)
```

This will spawn your prefab at the desired location, with the desired rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I found a solution.
So I made an child of my player and made it the position for spawning my bullet.

```
    Transform Spawnposition;

    Spawnposition =go.transform.FindChild("Fire");

    bulletInstance = Instantiate(bulletPrefab,Spawnposition.transform.position, 
    go.transform.rotation);
```

PS. My player is also a prefab.